# Does ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED affect Deletes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, locking, isolation-level

I have an exceptional circumstance that made me use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.  (I am using `sp_getapplock` to ensure single process access to a given row.)

I am trying my best to avoid any kind of lock escalation. I know clearly what `ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` does for reads, but I am not sure about deletes.

I saw some example code that was doing a delete using `ROWLOCK` and `READPAST`, along with `ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` but I was not clear on what that would do, so I have not been using it for now.

**Is that needed to prevent lock escalation of my deletes or is `ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` sufficient?**

Note:
In case there is interest, [here](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/2e02f80621bbab2f82575bf7794dd5f9#file-placelock-sql) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/2e02f80621bbab2f82575bf7794dd5f9#file-droplockinstance-sql) are the relevant sprocs for this question.

Comment: If you mean, should you be using `NOLOCK`/`READUNCOMMITED` when performing an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, with a `UPDATE`/`DELETE` the functionality is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Larnu - That is for table hints on a `FROM` clause.  I am just running a standalone `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` statement.

Comment: ...and then expecting that isolation level to affect deletes? How? Why would you even be trying to set that isolation level if your intention is to _change data_? Even if you already understand all of the risks of using it even just for _reading data_? See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/) for more background on Larnu's comment and using `READ UNCOMMITTED` in general.

Answer (score 6):

> I am failry clear on what ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED does for reads, but I am not sure about deletes.

It does nothing.  You can't modify the database without proper locking.  That would produce not just the failures and nonsense results that dirty reads produces, but would corrupt the database.